# In jmeter 5.4.3 v have used stoptest.sh command. Now am not able to run any Test suite . can someone help to solve it

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

error Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
on linux

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to provide a comprehensive answer without:

1. Knowing whether it is standalone or [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
2. What does [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) say
3. What does [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) say on all machines

If the `Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445` message is [absolutely normal](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.java#L1465), it's just an information that JMeter is listening for shutdown or dump signals

You should also see [Summariser](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode) output once per 30 seconds with some baseline statistical metrics looking like:

```
summary +      5 in 00:00:26 =    0.2/s Avg:   246 Min:    59 Max:   498 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary +      1 in 00:00:10 =    0.1/s Avg:   128 Min:   128 Max:   128 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
```

Demo:

[image]